# Multiple instances of programs allowed in windows firewall

Tags: security, windows-firewall

I am new to windows firewall. While allowing a program through windows firewall, I am able to find that multiple entries present for Firefox, and java. Why is it so ?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I too had couple of instances for Firefox exe. Is something related to updated versions added in firewall ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first 2 (common) reasons it might have 2 is "protocol" UDP and TCP

General points
If you start with the firewall actually turned on for both incomming and outgoing, things that try to get through do not until it is allowed, that can cause it to come up again, and be added again for the same thing as whatever program keeps trying. (so there are ways where you can have 2 completely same rules).

The other ton of things that can create multiple entries are all shown when you look at the rules created, and what they apply to. Which User, which ports, etc.
Profile,  loc address, remote add, protocol , loc and remote ports, user, and even computer.
Add to that the actual program item as shown in "program" might have variations, even though the "name" of the rule itself is a friendly sort of name , not the actual executable item.

If you find complete dupes, feel free to delete them, then test immediatly afterwards all aspects of the program, to inure operation. The reasoning for testing then, is because you know which item specifically you altered. Just dont assume they are dupes, unless you have examined all aspects of the rule created for that program. In all probability the second one covers a different "method".

You can de-duplicate, by giving "ANY" any , any  access to a program, I do not find that nessisary, and it probably isn't good form to blindly allow just anything anyway, but it is one way to reduce the list.
Because (old unused) rules dont leave the list on thier own , and most times are not uninstalled during uninstall operations for any programs, you could save more space and organise the rules more by deleting garbage, than by creating singles from doubles.

Conclusion: They are probably different in some way, check your "rules" for outgoing and incomming, view all the columns by spreading out the window, or the slower way look at all that the rule entails by double-clicking on it, and wading through the tabs.

Comment: Thanks for good answer. But I am not clear about the difference between "allowing a program through windows firewall" functionality and "Windows Firewall with advanced features" functionality of windows ? Does windows firewall internally maintains two lists of rules ? Or windows firewall maintains a single rulebook and both of these functionality affects the same rule book ?

Comment: I do not really know, indeed the only place my custom rules exist is in the outbound rules, even though both inbound and outbound traffic that does not match a rule is set to be blocked.  Which version of the windows OS are you running?